# Unable to import firebase in google cloud function

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, cloud, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to run a simple google cloud function that performs updating data in firebase db. When I deploy the function it throws error

I have installed python-firebase in my system. When i run the below code in my local system it updates the data in my db properly without any issue. But the same code throws error in cloud function

```
from firebase import firebase
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://db.firebaseio.com', None)
v = 10
firebase.put('/A',"Value",v)
```

When I run the same code in cloud function, deployment fails with the below error

```
File "/user_code/main.py", line 8, in <module>
from firebase import firebase
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase/__init__.py", line 3
from .async import process_pool
          ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In the requirements.txt I have included the below

```
requests
python-firebase
```

Comment: `async` is a keyword in Python 3.7

Comment: Ok. Since cloud function has only python 3.7, am not able to goto 3.6. Is there a workaround for this

Comment: https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase/commit/9fccf87303a27a6b7d871b0bae8336bb6070ff5b has fixed this. but the package on pip does not get updated yet. use it directly

Comment: Thanks for the info. But am writing this in cloud function. I can only provide the dependency in requirements.txt in the cloud function. I can't manually download and install this

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

I added the below in the requirements.txt

-e git://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase.git#egg=python-firebase

Its working now.